# Gradle 6.2.2 broke my bintray publishing (artifact names instead of version numbers)

Tags: gradle, artifactory, bintray

Since updating to gradle 6.2.2 the bintray publishing went nuts. Bintray shows the artifact names instead of the version numbers and the library is unuseable do to this.

- [Link to the bintray library](https://bintray.com/beta/#/emign/engineEmi/engineEmi?tab=overview)
- [Link to the build.gradle](https://github.com/emign/engineEmi/blob/master/build.gradle) file

[image]

Did anyone experience this or knows, why this is happening?

**EDIT**: Switching to a 5.6.3 gradle wrapper will upload the library as it is supposed to (without the artifact/version number naming issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newer *Gradle* versions publish more secure checksums as well. These checksums are not recognized by *Bintray* and thus it assumes, there's another version of the artifact. You should notice that all semantic versions are actually complete and that you could delete the non-versions.

To suppress publishing these checksums, you could add the following to your gradle properties.

```
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure=true
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out SO much. Thank you. Did you experience this yourself or did you just happen to realize whats wrong here?

Comment: I had the confusion myself; some time ago.

Comment: You dont happen to know the answer to this one then also? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595853/gradle-6-0-breaks-source-set-dependency

Answer (score 0):

Gradle team takes lead initiative in replacing `.md5` & `.sha1` with `.sha256` & `.sha512`.

I don't know who give them that "right" and the proper security is only package signing, so I see no reason for that breaking change (why push Apache & Sonatype & JFrog to patch their software??).

In `src/dependency-management/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/repositories/resolver/ExternalResourceResolver.java`:

```
public static boolean disableExtraChecksums() {
    return Boolean.getBoolean("org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure");
}

private void publishChecksums(ExternalResourceName destination, File content) {
    publishChecksum(destination, content, "sha1", 40);

    if (!ExternalResourceResolver.disableExtraChecksums()) {
        publishPossiblyUnsupportedChecksum(destination, content, "sha-256", 64);
        publishPossiblyUnsupportedChecksum(destination, content, "sha-512", 128);
    }
}
```

So the solution is to set system property `org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure` to `true`:

- `gradle -D org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure=true ...`
- `systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure = true` in `gradle.properties`
- `System.setProperty("org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure", "true")` in `settings.gradle`

See:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11308
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11412